# Converting integer to date/time from a different epoch

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

I am reading a timestamp from a device that comes over in integer format representing number of seconds since January 1, 2000. Using Python, how do I convert it to a readable date/time using Jan 1, 2000 as my epoch?

I have tried several `datetime` functions, but always end up with the incorrect date. I assume that Python automatically assumes a different epoch time than what I need (1970? It's 30 years off).

Here is the line of code I am currently using:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(z[i][2])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to help you, e.g.:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> base = datetime(2000, 1, 1) # start of your epoch
>>> base + timedelta(seconds=123456789) # add on a number of seconds
datetime.datetime(2003, 11, 29, 21, 33, 9)
```

You can also reverse the process using `timedelta.total_seconds`:

```
>>> (datetime.now() - base).total_seconds()
468696508.531
```

And you're right, [`fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) takes the number of seconds since 1970/1/1.

Comment: Awesome, looks like that fixed it. The line of code now looks like this: 'r3=base + timedelta(seconds=int(z[i][2]))'